# Planar graph with all drawing topologically isomorphic , but whose planar embending are not equivalent

Tags: graph-theory

I have to find an exemple on a 2-connected planar graph whose drawing are all topologically isomorphic but its planar embeddings are not equivalent. I thought  to use an cycle and some overturning to changes vertex order. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Consider a square with a diagonal. This graph can also be drawn as a triangle with an interior point adjacent to two vertices of the triangle.